Using clangd as a code hint in VScode to develop a Qt program
I used XMake as the build tool and was then able to compile properly. But I can't get good code hints again.
I don't know how I can get clangd to detect my Qt library.
So how should I set up the clangd plugin to accomplish my purpose? please!

Not familiar with xmake, but for first-class clangd support you'll want to generate the compilation database (compile_commands.json) through your build tools. Then clangd-aware IDEs (CLion, VSCode plugins, ...) can pick up linting from those files. See Getting Started with clangd.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I highly recommend programming in C or C++ and not mix them.  They are two separate languages.  The C++ language allows for overloading of operators and functions as well as exception handling.  This makes mixing with C more difficult because the linker has to come up with a naming scheme that satisfies both languages.  Much easier to program in C or C++ and remove the other tag.

The key is to generate a compile_commands.json file as @Rogue said. Bear is a simple way to do it, it should be able to wrap most build commands including xmake.
